# PyPi cannot find distribution for package "winrt", when it is clearly available

Tags: python, pypi

I've been trying to install the package `winrt` using pip, but whenever I try to I receive this error: (view image below)
[image]

even though it clearly exists (https://pypi.org/project/winrt/). How do I solve this? I've tried using `python -m pip install winrt` even though that's the same thing, I've also updated pip to 22.1.1. Anything else I can try? Thanks

EDIT: My PC meets the specified requirements:

1. Python 3.10.4
2. Windows 10 21H2 19044.1706
3. pip 21.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version `winrt` 1.0.21033.1 [provides binary wheels](https://pypi.org/project/winrt/1.0.21033.1/#files) for Python 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9 but not 3.10. Either downgrade your Python or compile from [sources](https://github.com/Microsoft/xlang/tree/master/src/package/pywinrt/projection).

Comment: Thanks! Also good job on the 69k reputation:)